# To show closedness of a subset in a metric spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $p\in X$, $\delta>0$ be fixed. Let

$$A=\{q \in X : p \in X, d(p,q)>\delta\}$$

How to show that $A$ is closed?

I tried to show that directly by taking $A$'s complement and show it is open but failed. I know when union boundary of some set becomes closed set, but I don't know how to prove it.

$d$ is a distance function, $X$ is an arbitrary metric space (not euclidean space)

I am studying analysis first nowadays, so I want you to do not "jump" throughout all proof. Thanks.

Comment: Is $p$ fixed or variable? What are the quantifiers? They matter, they are used for a reason. Do you mean "for all $p$"? "There is a $p$"? Is $\delta$ a constant, or a variable? Is it "for all $\delta$"? "There is a $\delta$"?

Comment: Also, some effort into spelling wouldn't go unappreciated. Instead of "uclid sp.", how about "Euclidean space"? Does not take that long to write, and people may be more inclined to give you suggestions as a result.

Comment: oh i didnt know that because this is the first question.

Comment: p and delta is fixed so these are constants

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual metric, and set $p=0$ and $\delta=1$. What is $A$ in that case?

Comment: The conclusion is not necessarily true if $p$ is fixed (the set is actually open) and even if $p$ is existential (i.e. it's the set of $q$ such that there is some $p$ a distance more than $\delta$ away), it's still false, since it's the projection onto the first component of the preimage of $(\delta, \infty)$ under the distance map $X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I think the conclusion is true if it's the set of $q$ such that every $p$ is at least a distance $\delta$ away because then the set is a union of isolated points.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $p\in X$ and $\delta > 0 $ are fixed (as stated in the comments), it seems clear that $A$ could be open (in fact this is the more "natural" conclusion, unless you can provide more details).  To see this, let $p=0\in \mathbb{R}^2=X$, and let $d$ be the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely, $d(x,y)=|x-y|=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$.  The set $A^c$ in this case is written

$$A^c=\{q\in \mathbb{R}^2 : |q| \le \delta \}$$

If $\delta=1$, we call $A$ the closed unit disc (or closed unit ball); and the complement of a closed set is open, so $A$ must be open.  If you have any further suspensions, one can easily check that $A^c$ is indeed closed (I'll leave this as an exercise, or consult any introductory book on point-set topology).